# How to search and return all matches in a column given multiple search criteria?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

[image]

In this example, I am searching for the color "red" and returning all instances of the item associated with that color. This was accomplished with the following formula in the Results column: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($D$2=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"")`.

I would like to find a way to accomplish this search, but instead return the items corresponding to multiple colors at once (e.g. "blue" and "green"). The problem I am encountering is that changing the search term `$D$2` to a range of values seems to break the formula.

I am looking for a modification of this formula or a new formula that can return all matches based on multiple (nth #) search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$8,$D$2:$D$3,0)), ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROWS($1:1))),"")`
By adding ISNUMBER & MATCH you're able to match a list. In this case values from `$D$2:$D$3`. You can change this range for your demand.
I also changed the `k`-argument for SMALL to `ROWS($1:1)` to start counting from where you paste your formula and count up when dragged down.
The formula should be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` as it's an array formula.